# filtering events with clientEvents method on fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i have a fullCalendar calendar working and now i want to use [clientEvents](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/) method to filter events like the following:

```
selecter_provider = "somevalue";
events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents', [event.provider == selected_provider]);
```

But i always get an empty array.

I suppose i'm not using the method properly, but i cannot find the way. Any clues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use filter as function like from [clientEvents DOCs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/clientEvents/)

> **idOrFilter** may also be a filter function that accepts one **Event Object** argument and returns **true** if it should be included in the result set.

*Code*

```
var selecter_provider = "somevalue";
var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) {
    return evt.provider == selecter_provider;
});
```